# Java Robot mouseMove issue on specific app

Tags: java

```
robot.mouseMove(x, y);
```

Doesn't work in the [BachinDraw](http://www.bachinmaker.com/?p=71) app window. But works in any other window.

What is blocking? At the same time, getPixelColor works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the program with administrator rights helped.